# Split pipe separated string - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with the following structure:

table1

```
f_name           f_content
test1.txt        |0002434299|354534|535345345|05|||BCV RESULT # 174|Test 12%|
test2.txt        |543566677|HTTYE|9w5w RRLL|05|||BBN RESULT # 144|Test 15#%|3
```

I need to separate f_content using pipes (|) and put appropriate position of the string.

The output table is:

```
f_name          position            value
test1.txt       1                   (null)
test1.txt       2                   0002434299
test1.txt       3                   354534
test1.txt       4                   535345345
test1.txt       5                   05
test1.txt       6                   (null)
test1.txt       7                   (null)
test1.txt       8                   BCV RESULT # 174
test1.txt       9                   Test 12%
test1.txt       10                  (null)

test2.txt       1                   (null)
test2.txt       2                   543566677
test2.txt       3                   HTTYE
test2.txt       4                   9w5w RRLL
test2.txt       5                   05
test2.txt       6                   (null)
test2.txt       7                   (null)
test2.txt       8                   BBN RESULT # 144
test2.txt       9                   Test 15#%
test2.txt       10                  3
```

I have over 500K records in table1. Each record has over 200 pipes.

Is there a way to write optimised query so that it can process 500K records with more than 200 pipes without filling the undo table space?

Can SQL query be written to process in chunks and keep inserting it in the output table?

Comment: If you have access to external resources, I would `bcp` out, use an awk script ot convert to whatever input format you need, and then `bcp` in. (Sorry can't remember the Oracle equivelant of `bcp`.) That will run in 3 seconds for 500K records with no worries. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what BCP is. Any reference link?

Comment: It's call SQLLoader, but the in-database solution from @MTO looks very good. I did a search for "Oracle database equivalent of bcp" and had to look at 2 articles before I found that. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need (slow) regular expressions, and can do this with simple string functions:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 ( f_name, f_content ) AS
SELECT 'test1.txt', '|0002434299|354534|535345345|05|||BCV RESULT # 174|Test 12%|' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'test2.txt', '|543566677|HTTYE|9w5w RRLL|05|||BBN RESULT # 144|Test 15#%|3' FROM DUAL

CREATE TABLE output_table (
  f_name   VARCHAR2(20),
  position NUMBER(4,0),
  value    VARCHAR2(50)
);
```

**Insert Statement**:

```
INSERT INTO output_table ( f_name, position, value )
WITH rsqfc ( f_name, f_content, idx, spos, epos ) AS (
  SELECT f_name, f_content, 1, 1, INSTR( f_content, '|', 1 )
  FROM   table1
UNION ALL
  SELECT f_name, f_content, idx + 1, epos + 1, INSTR( f_content, '|', epos + 1 )
  FROM   rsqfc
  WHERE  epos > 0
)
SELECT f_name,
       idx,
       CASE
         WHEN epos > 0
         THEN SUBSTR( f_content, spos, epos - spos )
         ELSE SUBSTR( f_content, spos )
       END
FROM   rsqfc
```

**Output**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   output_table
ORDER BY f_name, position
```

```
F_NAME    | POSITION | VALUE           
:-------- | -------: | :---------------
test1.txt |        1 | null            
test1.txt |        2 | 0002434299      
test1.txt |        3 | 354534          
test1.txt |        4 | 535345345       
test1.txt |        5 | 05              
test1.txt |        6 | null            
test1.txt |        7 | null            
test1.txt |        8 | BCV RESULT # 174
test1.txt |        9 | Test 12%        
test1.txt |       10 | null            
test2.txt |        1 | null            
test2.txt |        2 | 543566677       
test2.txt |        3 | HTTYE           
test2.txt |        4 | 9w5w RRLL       
test2.txt |        5 | 05              
test2.txt |        6 | null            
test2.txt |        7 | null            
test2.txt |        8 | BBN RESULT # 144
test2.txt |        9 | Test 15#%       
test2.txt |       10 | 3
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=980846061a7d73a65bd687f1ea488e25)*

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! Is there a way to break inserts without filling undo tablespace?

Comment: Is it possible to do create table as?

Comment: @dang Just use `CREATE TABLE` instead of `INSERT INTO`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp_substr()` window analytic function combined with `connect by level <= regexp_count(f_content,'\|')`

```
with t(f_name,f_content) as
(
 select 'test1.txt','|0002434299|354534|535345345|05|||BCV RESULT # 174|Test 12%|' 
   from dual
  union all  
 select 'test2.txt','|543566677|HTTYE|9w5w RRLL|05|||BBN RESULT # 144|Test 15#%|3' 
   from dual   
) 
select f_name,
       level as position,          
       replace( regexp_substr(replace(f_content,'|',' |'),
                                      '([^\|])+',
                                       1,
                                       level
                                      ),' ',null) as value                    
  from t
 connect by level <= regexp_count(f_content,'\|') + 1
     and prior f_name = f_name and prior sys_guid() is not null
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bf8c451c5ac50e14e6b892e171de6e77)</kbd>

Comment: Can SQL query be written to process in chunks and keep inserting it in the output table? My worry is the size of data which may fill up undo tablespace.

Comment: Also, the output is incorrect in the demo. The first value is null as it starts with |.

Comment: OK @dang I fixed. The rest ( performance, size .. etc. ) should be tested in your medium.

Comment: This is adding a space after each value.  Replace your regexp_replace() call with this to handle NULL list elements:  `regexp_substr(f_content, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, level, NULL, 1 )`

Comment: @Gary_W thank you for your caveat. I fixed by replacing one length spaces with nulls